# Play stores new account deletion Requirement for data safety

Tags: google-play

I recently found a new data safety requirement from the Play Store that users can delete their account from the app if they want, from the Play Store. The developer should give a web link for that.

In my application, I use a Firebase phone number authentication. Inside the app, there is a profile creation section for the user. The app also collects some sensitive information like payment details. My app does not have an account deletion feature inside the app. Now I am preparing to submit my app to the Play Store.

Should I include this feature or is there any way to skip this part? If I skip this part what will happen? I did not see any app that provided this account deletion link on their Play Store listing page. Is there any app currently on the Play Store which have this feature?

Comment: You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to create a Node.js file for deleting user accounts. Deploy it as a Cloud Function on Google Cloud Platform to trigger it in response to events or HTTP requests. This function securely deletes user accounts and optionally preserves sensitive data like payment details. Just add a boolean parameter like "deleted": "true" in your "payment collection" to keep payment details. Update your app's query to show only "deleted": null or false payment data.

Comment: And account delete options are available in most common apps like whatsapp, instagram etc.